# How to generate PDF file using X++?

Tags: pdf, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, pdfa

Can I create simple pdf file in x++? In this pdf I would like to have for example select from one table or simple static text.

Comment: Are you asking in general or for a specific version of Dynamics AX/365? Also are you aware that every report can be "printed" as an pdf file?

Comment: In Dynamics AX 2012, yes I know that reports are printed as pdf but I would like to have simple pdf, not report with 1 or 2 line text.

Comment: It still may be the easiest way to achieve what you want. I'm not sure how you can access the pdf generation capabilities of AX directly (or even if it is possible). Other than that you could start looking into third party pdf generators and how they can be integrated with AX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MorphX reports can be saved to PDF by [using the proper print settings beforehand](http://axwonders.blogspot.dk/2011/02/save-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-report.html).

SSRS reports can do this also [using similar tricks](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxinsightbyanas/archive/2016/02/01/ax-2012-print-ssrs-report-in-pdf-to-disk).

Another way is to generate RTF, [then let Word do the PDF creation](http://axhelpdesk.blogspot.dk/2013/06/convert-word-documents-into-pdf-report.html). Silly, but maybe the PDF is smaller or better looking.

It is possible, but not simple, to generate PDF directly by using [third party .Net components](https://www.google.dk/search?&q=.net%20PDF%20generation).

Answer (score 3):

Some weeks ago, I used the Evo HTML to PDF library http://www.evopdf.com/ to convert simple HTML templates to PDF and it worked great. It can convert plain text as well, so maybe it could be useful for you.
Natively, AX hasn't anything to create PDF files.