# SSRS PDF Export AX 2012 R3

Tags: pdf, axapta, ssrs-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

We are using Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3.

Where can I found the code in exporting PDF file in SSRS Report Viewer?

Is it possible to alter the standard exporting of PDF file from **SSRS**?
Clients requirements is to export the generated report in **SSRS** Report Viewer in **PDFX** format. **PDFX** is just the same with **PDF**.

What we are thinking is to alter the code behind in SSRS Exporting, to rename the file extension from **.pdf** into **.pdfx**

Is it doable or possible? And how it would be done?

Kindly advise

Comment: Have you had a look at the Reporserver config file on your Reporting server? It's an XML configuration file..  It is called rsreportserver.config

Comment: what's that XML config file all about?

Comment: The xml files shows you what formats the reports can export  in amongst other things..  You can add your own extensions.. tab for example .. Or like pdfx that you require. Just make sure you back up the file first.

Comment: how about the code in generating pdf file? it seems it's just like having an choices in save file type.

Comment: Yes.. that's the basic..  there are other options you can add to customise it.  Might have to Google that bit sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How togenerate PDF file using X++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833607)